# jquery range utility for quick iteration (prototype's $R equivalent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, prototypejs, range

In prototype the cumbersome for:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) { ... }
```

can be written as

```
$R(0, 10).each(function(i){ ... });
```

Is there an equivalent of range in JQuery ?

Comment: Interesting how the "cumbersome" first example is fewer characters than the second example. It will also run faster.

Comment: Admittedly, the first example does have the downside of putting the loop variable `i` in the current scope (or the global scope if there's no `var i` elsewhere in this scope).

Comment: Maybe not in the above example, since it's dealing with numbers specifically which are not indexes, but when iterating over a collection, all those i's in `var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)` and  object access as `x[i]` are pure hassle when all that's needed is going over each object in a collection and doing something with it (nothing to do with indexes). Collection iteration and manipulation methods such as `map, filter, any, all, each, reduce, ..` should be part of each language and I am glad the ES5 spec includes these.

Comment: Is easier for my brain to think in terms of range-iteration instead of condition-loop-increment I guess, anyway, a range thingy is good to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/source/browse/trunk/src/jquery.arrayUtils.js?r=452

jQuery does not provide range expansion natively, but it's an easy addition. There are only two parts to it. First the range function should return an array with the each item in the range expanded to an array value. Next add a method to `Array` to iterate each object passing in a handler function.

Here we define `forEach` that's part of the ECMA-262 standard for iterating over arrays. See [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more details.

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}
```

Next, we need a function to expand ranges to an array within the jQuery namespace. Taken from the above URL (original source - http://blog.outofhanwell.com/2006/03/29/javascript-range-function/)
:

```
$.extend({
    // Returns a range object
    // Author: Matthias Miller
    // Site:   http://blog.outofhanwell.com/2006/03/29/javascript-range-function/
    range:  function() {
        if (!arguments.length) { return []; }
        var min, max, step;
        if (arguments.length == 1) {
            min  = 0;
            max  = arguments[0]-1;
            step = 1;
        }
        else {
            // default step to 1 if it's zero or undefined
            min  = arguments[0];
            max  = arguments[1]-1;
            step = arguments[2] || 1;
        }
        // convert negative steps to positive and reverse min/max
        if (step < 0 && min >= max) {
            step *= -1;
            var tmp = min;
            min = max;
            max = tmp;
            min += ((max-min) % step);
        }
        var a = [];
        for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) { a.push(i); }
        return a;
    }
});
```

Alrighty, now we can do:

```
$.range(2, 10).forEach(function(v) {
    console.log(v); // 2, 3, 4, .., 9
});
```

Or use it with a custom step value instead of 1

```
$.range(2, 20, 4).forEach(function(v) {
    console.log(v); // 2, 6, 10, 14, 18
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer a generator to an array - more elegant (imho) and more memory efficient.

```
function Range(low, high){
  this.low = low;
  this.high = high;
}
Range.prototype.__iterator__ = function(){
  for (var i = this.low; i <= this.high; i++)
    yield i;
};
```

Then you can simply

```
var range = new Range(3, 5);
for (var i in range)
  print(i); // prints 3, then 4, then 5 in sequence
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Iterators_and_Generators